# Jquery: How to detect Input[type="time"] is almost or completely filled

Tags: jquery, input, time, is-empty, hour

I can not find solution to detect that an input type time is almost (hour) or completely (hour + minute) filled .

This solution could allow me to prevent that a period is completely write:
ex : morning and afternoon : from 08h00 to 19h00 (24h)

I create a condition to form submission which display a message error if morning or afternoon isn't filled.

(If After submission I have that : from {08h00} to {..h..} ) :

If afternoon is finally filled , return true .

If afternoon doesn't exist condition is applied to morning to verify if it's erased - then the message error is removed .
But it seems that Jquery defined an input type time empty as soon as "minute" part is erased using on.('keyup') function to determined each moment of user erased .

Many user doesn't know clicking outside the input field after deletion allow me to detect erased input, so I can't use .blur() function.

```
For this configuration: 
from {08h..} to {..h..} . first input has class "classofinput".
jQuery('classofinput').val() === ""; or jQuery('classofinput').length == 0;
Jquery return true
or jQuery('classofinput').val() !== ""; or jQuery('classofinput').length > 0;
Jquery return false
```

Edit - Code example : [Codepen Input[type="time"]](https://codepen.io/Artenis/pen/QWxJpLV)

```
//Html
<input type="time">

//Jquery
//If somebody has a solution ?
$(document).on("change", "input", function () {
   console.log($(this).val());
});
//doesn't work
//Keyup, keydown, blur, focusIn or FocusOut , change, text(), html().
/* 1
$('input').blur(function () {
   console.log($(this).val());
});
*/
/* 2
setTimeout(function(){
   console.log($(this).val());
});
*/
/* 3
console.log($(this).delay(20).val());
*/
```

Comment: does `jquery`'s `keyup` or `keydown` event not satisfied your need? or maybe you need a bit of delay? how does the time being put into the input field anyway?

Comment: here a test : https://codepen.io/Artenis/pen/QWxJpLV. Keyup, keydown, blur, focusIn or FocusOut don't change anything. Html input type Time seems to be not created to return separately each value from either side of colon. Even with delay() or setTimeout(). The time is put manually by user and after got and displayed from server

Comment: I don't know why in 2022 and almost 2023 the W3C and WHATWG don't allow this verification .

Comment: umm, have you tried `on` `change` event? it would be nice to have snippets on the question though, not some external site that might be gone before stackoverflow does.

Comment: also, input other than `text` and `file` may behave differently on different browser. which is why, most ux developer relies on polyfills like (arguably) jquery datepicker to make sure they behave uniformly - and have more controls while at it.

Comment: I tried but doesn't change anything: on.('change'), .text(), .html().
I work with input type Time, "file" is off topic. I add code example in the subject.

Comment: Bagus Tesa , I need a solution for all browsers . If it doesn't work, I will search other solutions.

Comment: @Bagus Tesa, I used also a personal input text but it require more code and page will load a little more slowly : I used input text for period for every morning and afternoon for : all days of event and every day of the week and each day between start and end date of event generated by user.